# Should I include namespace hints in class names?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

If I have a set of interfaces which may have several implementations (i.e. in-memory, NHibernate, xml-based, etc.), is it wise to provide namespace hints in the class names themselves? For example:

```
MyDomain.Infrastructure.ISomeProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.ISomeOtherProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.IYetAnotherProvider
```

I might then have:

```
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBased.SomeProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBased.SomeOtherProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBased.YetAnotherProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.XmlFileBased.SomeProvider // etc...
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.NHibernate.SomeProvider // etc...
```

vs.

```
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBased.MemoryBasedSomeProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBased.MemoryBasedSomeOtherProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBased.MemoryBasedYetAnotherProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.XmlFileBased.XmlSomeProvider // etc...
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.NHibernate.NHibernateSomeProvider // etc...
```

In the second case, it's clear which implementation I am using anywhere in my code by the class name itself, but it seems a bit redundant to group them by namespace and then include it in the class name anyway, no?

A third option might be:

```
MyDomain.Infrastructure.ISomeProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBasedSomeProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBasedSomeOtherProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBasedYetAnotherProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.XmlSomeProvider // etc...
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.NHibernateSomeProvider // etc...
```

I have eliminated the redundant namespaces, but now the only way to group / organize the classes is by class name prefix. I suppose I could separate them into folders and manually adjust the namespaces in any newly created files. Are there any clear advantages for one of these styles over the others?

Comment: down-voted, and vote-to-close - seriously? this is a very good question.

Comment: The problem with giving your users the ability to police the content is that you'll inevitably have users that choose to abuse that privilege for no real reason at all other than to boost their sense of superiority.

Comment: True, well looks like you have 3x +1's so the trend is moving in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1

```
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBased.SomeProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBased.SomeOtherProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.MemoryBased.YetAnotherProvider
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.XmlFileBased.SomeProvider // etc...
MyDomain.Infrastructure.Impl.NHibernate.SomeProvider // etc...
```

Would be my preferred option. You could argue that you should have them in different projects per implementation (In memory, ORM, XML) and then the required implementation could be loaded in at runtime depending on your IoC container and requirements at the time.

To mess around with namespaces and add in the type of implementation in the name of the class is overkill and will make your namespaces look pointless to external/other developers.

Comment: But if there is an abstract base class what would the name be? `MyDomain.Infrastructure.Base.Infrastructure` ?

Comment: Like all good things in development it would depend.

It could be `MyDomain.Infrastructure.BaseProvider`?

Answer (score 4):

Good question. I'll answer it with another, how likely is it that someone will need to use multiple implementations of `ISomeProvider` at one time? If so, having them disambiguated simply by namespace will result in the need for some nasty fully qualified namespaces.

If not, I'd use the namespace to indicate the nature of the implementation, but share the same names throughout. Either way, the fact that your API is defined by interfaces rather than concrete implementations, means that people can interchange the implementation very easily regardless of which option you go for.